# Regular expression with captured groups for parsing a range of two real numbers

Tags: java, android, regex, regex-group

I need a regex to properly parse ranges of two real numbers (unsigned), presented with a hyphen.

Valid inputs:

> 1-3
>
> 3.14-7.50
>
> 0-4.01

It's Java on Android.

My current approach:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<Minimum>\\d+(\\.\\d+))-(?<Maximum>\\d+(\\.\\d+))");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("3.14-5.2");
String min = matcher.group("Minimum");
String max = matcher.group("Maximum");
```

It crashes on attempting to retrieve the minimum.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.getMatchedGroupIndex(Matcher.java:1314)
    at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:572)
```

I can't really see what's wrong with the expression.

I would particularly appreciate an explanation on what the problem with it is. A regex allowing for optional white space around the hyphen would be extra nice, too (I'd like it to work that way but I dropped this for now as I can't get it to work at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make decimal part optional:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
   "(?<Minimum>\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)-(?<Maximum>\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)");
```

- `?` after `(?:\\.\\d+)` will make that group an optional match
- Better to use `?:` for making it a non-capturing group

Also you need to call `matcher.find()` or `matcher.matches()` before calling `.group(int)` method.

Comment: No, that is not related, but surely that would be the next question.

Comment: Oh yes, `find()` or `matches()` need to be called before `.group()`

Comment: Right! Thanks. Thank you too @WiktorStribiżew